# ServiceStack -is there a trick to using ProfiledDbConnection with async

Tags: c#, async-await, servicestack

I just converted some code to async await...example:

```
public async Task<User> StoreAsync(User user)
{
    using (var db = DbFactory.Open())
    {
        await db.SaveAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    return user;
}
```

**(I did try also without the ConfigureAwait(false) )**

And of course the uses of it were changed:

```
await UserRepo.StoreAsync(user);
```

And the method signature:

```
public async Task<RegisterExpertResponse> Post(RegisterExpert request)
```

Everything worked fine previously and everything works fine still if I comment out the as below:

```
    var connectionString = ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider)
        // Commented out because it fails with "unable to cast object of type Servicestack.MiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbCommand to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand"
        //{ ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current) }
    );
```

If I comment the Connection filter back in I get:

> unable to cast object of type
>   Servicestack.MiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbCommand to
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

(All latest prod release servicestack nuget packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [v4.0.40 of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#4040-release-notes) that was just released should now support profiling OrmLite Async API's in MiniProfiler.